# APNS P12 certificate stopped working?

Tags: ios, asp.net, security, ssl, pushsharp

I am using ASP.NET server to send push notification to APNS. I am using PushSharp library. Suddenly, push notification stopped working. I got this exception,

```
The maximum number of Send attempts to send the notification was reached
```

I searched and found that APNS is no longer support SSL v3. https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10222014a and I found that the latest version of library is also using Tls. So I updated the library. But now I am getting,

```
System.IO.IOException: Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
```

My .p12 certficate validity is 3/4/2014 to 3/4/2015. I have generated the .p12 cert file when APNS support SSL v3. Will I need to update the p12 certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the APNS certificate(.p12 file) and PushSharp library which is now using TLS instead of SSL v3.0(which is vulnerable to POODLE). Now the problem is fixed.